# A possible dynamical approach to the "Invariant Subspace Problem"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, operator-theory, open-problems, differential-operators

In the literature, is there any paper or research investigating [the invariant subspace problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem) with consideration of  differential operators acting on an appropriate  Sobolev space?In particular is there any  research investigating the "Invariant Subspace Conjecture"  via derivational operator arising from vector fields which generate a minimal  dynamical system? Namely those vector fields without proper  compact invariant sets or vector fields whose all trajectories are dense.

A vector field $X$ on a manifold $M$ defines a derivation on the space of smooth functions. What is a relevant Hilbert space of functions invariant under the $X$-derivation? (A kind of infinite order Sobolov space.) Let's denote this Hilbert space by $H^{\infty}(M)$. Is there any research on the invariant subspaces of the derivations on the infinite order Sobolev space?
Of course there is an obvious $1$-dimensional invariant subspace of constant functions, but I guess that this trivial space can be ignored with some Hilbert space techniques.

As a  particular  case:

Is there a smooth vector field $X$  on the torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ which is tangent to a Kronecker foliation $dx+\theta dy=0$ for some irrational number $\theta$, with an invariant subspace not degenerated to the trivial $1$-dimensional subspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following papers are related to your question:

1. A. Atzmon, A model for operators with cyclic adjoint, *Integral
   equations and Operator theory*, 10(1987), 153-163.
2. A. Atzmon, Nuclear Frechet spaces of entire functions with transitive
   differentiation, *J. Analyse Math.* 60(1993), 1-19.

A.Atzmon

Comment: @A.Atzmon  Dear Prof. Atzmon thank you very much for your very excelent answer and your attention to my question. You are mostly well come to  MO.

Answer (score 4):

Nice try, but I don't think this will help with the ISP.

I think of the "$X$-derivation" as an unbounded skew-adjoint operator $D$ on $L^2(M)$. When you say "Sobolev space" I suppose you mean to take the domain of $D$, equipped with the square norm $\|f\|^2_2 + \|Df\|^2_2$. I'm not sure what you mean about an infinite order space.

Anyway, working on $L^2(M)$ the operator $D$ is $i$ times a self-adjoint operator, so by spectral theory you can go to a multiplication picture in which $D$ becomes multiplication by a purely imaginary function. In this picture you can see that there are lots of invariant subspaces contained in the domain of $D$, i.e., the Sobolev space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The derivation is a bounded opertor from $H^s(M)$ to $H^{s-1}(M)$. Now i search for a legal situation of $s=\infty$. Then a natural question is the decomposition of $H^{\infty}(M)$ to irreducible component.(The component without invariant subspace)

Comment: That's not going to work, for the same reason given in my answer. When you work in the spectral multiplication picture it's clear that there are lots of subspaces --- e.g., the spectral projection of $iD$ for any bounded interval --- which are invariant under $D^n$ for all $n$.